# What is the main difference between invoking function with or without paranthesis?

Tags: python

I fell in doubt why below two code work correctly and what is the difference with or without paranthesis?
And I see some answered question about first part.

**Firts part**

```
def hello():
pass
hello# first
hello()#second
```

Then I compile following two examples,again it works but I get different result for second part.

**Second part**

```
df["method"].value_counts()#first
```

[image]

```
df["method"].value_counts# second
```

[image]

**My Questions**

1-)Why are the results different?

2-)After `df["method]` `".value_counts"` Are the expressions with parentheses and expressions without parentheses different things? Like method or function.

Comment: The main difference is that `hello` doesn't invoke the function *at all*.

Comment: The entire output of the second is just part of some type's `__repr__` method, unrelated to the actual data frame's contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hello` is a function itself. Actually, it is a pointer to bytes (wow!) representing underlying algorithm, an essence of your function. So you don't **invoke** function in such a way, you reference it. For example, `myFunc = hello` is perfectly valid Python code and you can pass both `hello` directly and `myFunc` as arguments to other functions. Same applies to lambdas, `x = lambda (): print('hi')` is also valid code.

`()` after some function make it run, i.e. you **invoke** it, enforce encoded algorithm to return some result. If you don't use `()` to invoke your functions, nothing will ever happen, they won't run, they wont use your CPU to compute something, your program will be dead no matter how good it's code is.

Comment: Now I got first part I know logic of pointer. But in second part why the result are different?

Comment: @KerimTurak because there is notion of "standard string representation" for each Python type whatsoever. What you see is the way function represents itself. No magic there, just Python-specific stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Well, functions are also variables, think of them as executable variables.

```
def hello():
  pass

hello # first
hello() # second
```

So basically the first version is reading the variable, and the second version is executing the variable.

When Python reads those lines it sees `hello` and it's like "Oh yeah, I know `hello`, it's a function" but that's all it's going to do.
Then it reads `hello()` and it's like "Oh you want me to execute it? Sure, here it goes".

If you change hello's definition to this one you'll see the difference more clearly.

```
def hello():
  print("I am executing a function")
  pass
```

The first version is going to say "Oh yeah, I know hello, that's a function".
The second version is going to print "I am executing a function" because of the parens.

Answer (score 0):

`hello` is a referece to a value of type `function`. `hello()` is Python syntax for invoking a value's `__call__` method, equivalent here to `hello.__call__()`. The parentheses are a request to actually *call* the function bound to the name `hello`.